# $(this) в функции

Tags: jquery

Сделал залипание при наведении. Но `$(this)` в функции `undefined`.

Как возможно в `setTimeout( function(){` получить `$(this)`?

```
var tout;
$('.scroll-posters').on({
        mouseenter: function() {
           //создаём таймер который ждёт 5 секунд и запускает ваш метод
          tout=setTimeout(function(){

                 // здесь расположена вся ваша логика
                 // которая запускается в случае если пользователь держит указатель 5 секунд.
                 alert("Вы продержали 5 секунд"+ $(this).html());
                 $(this).fadeOut();
          },1000);
        },
        mouseleave: function() {
        $('#test-text').empty();
        $(this).children('.pop').animate({opacity:0, width:0, height:0, top:'auto', left:'auto'},50);
           clearTimeout(tout);
        }
    }, '.poster-block');
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

у setTimeout контекст window, сделайте перед ним var $t=$(this); и используйте вместо $(this)

```
var tout;
$('.scroll-posters').on({
        mouseenter: function() {
           //создаём таймер который ждёт 5 секунд и запускает ваш метод
          var $t=$(this); // !!! тут
          tout=setTimeout(function(){

                 // здесь расположена вся ваша логика
                 // которая запускается в случае если пользователь держит указатель 5 секунд.
                 alert("Вы продержали 5 секунд"+ $t.html());
                 $t.fadeOut();
          },1000);
        },
        mouseleave: function() {
        $('#test-text').empty();
        $(this).children('.pop').animate({opacity:0, width:0, height:0, top:'auto', left:'auto'},50);
           clearTimeout(tout);
        }
    }, '.poster-block');
```

btw: undifained это действительно удивительно.